# How to divide an entire column by the sum of it's average in excel

Tags: excel

Hello I have a large file in excel. I was able to calculate the average for an entire column by using `=AVERAGE(A2:A34315)` and got it's average. Now i'm trying to divide the entire column by it's average. Is there an easier way to do this without me going into a new column and manually typing it. For example let's take the average number to be 1000

```
=A2/1000
```

I don't want to type this all the time or drag because the file i have is large. The columns start from 2 all the way to 34315. Reason for doing this is i'm trying to normalize or scale the data.

Comment: In cell B2, type in `=A2/$A$9999` Where A99999 is wherever you keep your averaged value. Then simply double click on the bottom right corner of your cell.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq but do i have to drag it?

Comment: @user3497437  What happened when you double clicked on the bottom right corner of the adjacent cell when you double clicked on it?

Comment: @ForwardEd nothing happened? Had option of 3 saying copy cells fill with formatting, and fill without formatting

Comment: What version of excel are you running?  I am running excel 2013.  When I select the cell where I just enter the formula, the cell is surrounded by a thick line and in the bottom right corner there is a slightly larger than the line square.  When I double click this square, the range to the bottom of the adjacent column is selected provided there are no gaps in the data.  if there is a gap it will select to the row just above the gap.

Comment: @ForwardEd actually running this on mac. version 2011

Comment: I would recommend recording a macro of you doing the procedure once.  Then stop the recording.  from there you can assign that recording to repeat the copy of column A to column be for the number of rows multiple times.  If you need to copy B to C and Then C to D or in other words copy the last column to the next column every time you press a button, you can do that with that recorded macro, it will just need to be edited.  If you copy and past that recording into your question we can help you edit it.

Comment: Another trick I used to do was put a dummy row of data just below the last row of data I was working with and copy it across.  That when when I wanted to paste something to the entire column I would selecte a cell at the top, and while holding the shift key I would press the end key once and then press the down arrow.  This would select the entire column plus my dummy row.  Then I would press the up arrow once so the dummy row was not part of the selection and then I would go ahead and paste.

Comment: here is a link on [how to record a macro in Excel for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/288117)

Comment: Is there text in B1? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

The following short procedure takes the [AVERAGE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047BAC88-D466-426C-A32B-8F33EB960CF6) of all of the numbers in column A and stores it in B1. It then disguises the number with a custom number format that looks like a common column header label. The underlying value is used to 'scale' or 'normalize' the numbers from column A into column B.

```
Sub scaled()
    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        .Range("B1").Formula = "=average(a:a)"
        .Range("B1").NumberFormat = "\S\c\a\l\e"
        .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=a2/b$1"
    End With
End Sub
```

You could use a formula in column B like `=A2/AVERAGE(A:A)` but that calculates the same average over and over again. Calculating it once and leaving it 'hidden' should be much more efficient.

Comment: For my learning, can you please say what it represents the line .Range("B1").NumberFormat = "\S\c\a\l\e"

Comment: After putting the average of A:A into B1, it hides the number with a custom number format. The backslashes escape each character to create a literal string so reserved characters like **s** don't try to represent *seconds*. I don't know what actually is in B1 so I escaped them all hoping that the OP would try and imitate that. tbh, you only need `"\Sc\al\e"` for **Scale** to show.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code

if you need individual percentage then add `Range("B" & i).NumberFormat = "0.00%"`

```
Sub getavg()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim avgg As Variant
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    avgg = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("A2:A" & lastrow))
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Range("B" & i).Value = Range("A" & i).Value / avgg
        'Range("B" & i).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
    Next i
End Sub
```